# Is it safe to use the django safe filter in text only emails?

Tags: python, django, django-templates, sanitization

When crafting the text only version of an email, is it safe to use the 'safe' filter on untrusted content?

```
 # text_email.txt
 Dear User,

 Please see below some user-submitted content:

 {{ untrusted_content|safe }}

 Yours, etc.
```

Comment: why not? it's just a text.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Yes.**

As long as you are *enforcing that the email is sent as **text***, then any **HTML** (or other unsafe content) **should not be rendered by email clients**, but instead the source will just be shown as text.